# How could the comet news impact Orlean’s party’s chances of winning?

Tags: dont-look-up

Dr. Oglethorpe informs US President Orlean of the government’s plans to
address the threat posed by the comet through NASA. He suggests using drones
equipped with nuclear weapons to alter the comet’s orbit. Dr. Oglethorpe emphasizes
the need for immediate action to prevent a potential catastrophe:

> US President Orlean: Oh, hey. All right, all right, all right. When
> are the midterms?
>
> Jason: Three weeks.
>
> US President Orlean: **So, if this breaks before then, we lose
> Congress**.

US President Orlean is concerned that if news about the comet heading towards Earth becomes
public before the midterm elections, it could negatively impact her party’s chances of winning.

How could the comet news impact Orlean’s party’s chances of winning?

Comment: Because she'd get blamed for it.

Comment: "Intelligence has nothing to do with politics!"

Comment: I can think of a dozen reason. Maybe she's been weak on science spending and thinks this will be used against her by her political opponents. Maybe she's counting on a bump from campaigning and this news will swamp the airwaves, etc etc

Comment: I don't think this is answerable, tbh. The point is to show that she's a moron who puts her narrow own interests at the forefront of her thinking.

Comment: @Valorum - that would be an answer, actually